# Logging out of a network share drive without reboot?

Tags: windows-xp, network-shares

I have a small script that runs on each workstation which runs defrag and chkdsk and connect each workstation temporarily to a network share that they, normally, do not have access to. The command I use to connect to them is:

```
net use \\server\sharename [password] /USER:domain\username P:No
```

Is there a command to log that user out of the drive share without restarting the computer?

Workstations run on Windows XP SP3

EDIT: I've used:

```
net use \\server\sharename /delete
```

but the command returns "The network connection cannot be found". However, I can still navigate to `\\server\sharename` in MyComputer address line and have full access to it still.

EDIT2: Assume I've read through the help files for net use   ;D

EDIT3: Would a reboot suffice? Yes... however it is more convenient to log the user out of the share instead =D. I know I'm difficult.

Comment: Have you tried `Net Use * /Del`?

Comment: we other user shares associated to the login, and we do not wish to remove all of them. Just the one that we've temporarily allowed the user access to.

Comment: I (mostly) meant for testing purposes.  But I think I see what's going on here, so I've added an 'answer'. :)

Comment: See [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/a/1047434/63361). You may also need to do `klist purge`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
net use \\server\sharename /delete
```

EDIT:
To cause the credentials to get flushed:

```
net use \\server\IPC$ /delete
```

Comment: hmm, usually SU notifies me sooner if an answer is added when I'm typing, +1 for being first.

Comment: I've tried this, but the command returns "The network connection cannot be found." However, I can still access the network share freely.\

Comment: I'm so dumb... double checked my code this morning and found I had a trailing \ on after the sharename... tested it and yep the trailing slash makes a difference. Sorry for my n00bizm

Comment: I tried `net use \\server\IPC$ /delete` and it gives the error `The network connection could not be found`.

Comment: `net use * /del` can be used as a shotgun approach if you don't have any other connections you mind destroying (`net use` by itself will list them). After that, if it still doesn't work, restart the *Workstation* service instead of rebooting.

Comment: I've found that this is not sufficient to log out of a network share *BUT* see the answer by Jason C to use 'net stop Workstation' and restart the service to log out of a share without rebooting. I've found that 'net stop Workstation' will hang if File Explorer is open on a share being disconnected.

Answer (score 4):

If the `net use` commands listed here do not do the trick, instead of rebooting, you can just restart the *Workstation* service (I'm not sure how to do this [without the service restart](https://superuser.com/questions/883604/disconnecting-switching-users-on-windows-network-share-without-restarting-work) though):

1. First use the appropriate `net use` commands as above (e.g. `net use * /del` for the shotgun approach).
2. Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
3. Find *Workstation* in the list.
4. Right click and choose **Restart**.

If you have any explorer windows open for the shared folder, or any open files, you may have to close them in order for the service to restart (if the restart appears to hang this is usually why).

Alternatively you can restart the service on the command line with:

```
net stop Workstation
net start Workstation
net start "Computer Browser"
```

The *Computer Browser* start is usually necessary as stopping *Workstation* also stops *Computer Browser*. You'll see if it does in the output from the first command. Again, closing explorer windows and open files may be necessary.

---

Reference: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58494ea1-e3a0-49ab-be5c-1aa2b86f13c9/how-to-logout-from-shared-folder

Comment: `net start "Computer Browser"` returns `The service name is invalid`. Has the service name changed?

Answer (score 3):

```
net use \\server\sharename /delete
```

See the full net use command [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/net_use.mspx?mfr=true).

Answer (score 0):

@rocketsarefast and I have discovered another way to clear the network credentials. I have posted my answer in this thread:

- How do I remove login credentials for a network location in Win7?:

  https://serverfault.com/questions/213765/how-do-i-remove-login-credentials-for-a-network-location-in-win7/853860#853860

---

I have also discovered from [@rocketsarefast's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/213765/how-do-i-remove-login-credentials-for-a-network-location-in-win7/653589#653589) that Windows will clear the old network credentials when there is a new login attempt.

However, his `net use "\\10.0.0.5\c$" "badpassword" /user:"baduser"` command is way too slow, especially when the client has to wait up to several seconds for the server to respond with a rejection, which is terrible and inconvenient.

For my use case, I was able to use the Win32 API to map the network share `\\Server\Share` to the `S:\` drive. It disconnects the drive first and then prompts the user with the Windows network login dialog so that the person can logout and login as a different user.

Here is the C code `main.c`:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif

#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0500

#pragma comment(lib, L"mpr.lib")

#include <windows.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

int wmain(const size_t argc, const wchar_t** argv) {
    NETRESOURCE networkResource = {0};
    networkResource.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    networkResource.lpLocalName = L"S:";
    networkResource.lpRemoteName = L"\\\\Server\\Share";
    networkResource.lpProvider = NULL;

    DWORD result = 0;
    result = WNetCancelConnection2(networkResource.lpLocalName, CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE, TRUE);
//    wprintf(L"WNetCancelConnection2 result: %d\n", result);

    result = WNetAddConnection2(&networkResource, NULL, NULL, CONNECT_INTERACTIVE | CONNECT_PROMPT);
//    wprintf(L"WNetAddConnection2 result: %d\n", result);

//    getchar();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(MapNetworkDrive)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c11 -g3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS} -municode -mwindows")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.c)
add_executable(MapNetworkDrive ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(MapNetworkDrive mpr.lib)
```

Compile using MinGW-w64 - for 32 and 64 bit Windows:

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/

As an alternative to C, here is an easy C# tutorial on the API:

- Mapping a Drive Letter Programmatically:

  http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/mapdriveletter.aspx

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.