# Disconnecting / logging out from Windows network share without restarting Workstation service

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares

I have a file server running (SMB) that I connected to in Explorer (Windows 7 Professional) by visiting \\1.2.3.4 directly. I logged in as one user, without saving credentials, and now wish to log out (actually I want to change to a different user, but being able to log out in general would be useful).

I have searched around for ways to do this and found a bunch of info that suggests using some form of `net use \\1.2.3.4 /del`:

- [How to logout from a Windows shared folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/482082/how-to-logout-from-a-windows-shared-folder)
- [How do I change the user I am logged in with on a Network Share?](https://superuser.com/questions/123833/how-do-i-change-the-user-i-am-logged-in-with-on-a-network-share)
- [Using Different Credentials to Access Shared Folders in Windows 7](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/using-different-credentials-to-access-shared-folders-in-windows-7/) (www.raymond.cc)
- [How do I remove login credentials for a network location in Win7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/213765/how-do-i-remove-login-credentials-for-a-network-location-in-win7) (serverfault.com)
- [Logging out of a network share drive without reboot?](https://superuser.com/questions/327974/logging-out-of-a-network-share-drive-without-reboot?rq=1)
- Etc.

However, none of these actually seemed to work for me. I run `net use * /del`, then use `net use` to verify that the list is empty, and yet the share mysteriously remains in explorer, unaffected, accessible, and still using the previous login.

Another thing I tried, which also failed, was doing e.g. `net use \\1.2.3.4 /user:newusername` to switch the credentials. However, *even when `net use` showed an empty connection list*, this still produced an error stating that multiple connections to the same resource with different users were not allowed - why there  were connections that didn't show up in `net use`'s list is a mystery to me.

I then found this article [How to logout from shared folder](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/58494ea1-e3a0-49ab-be5c-1aa2b86f13c9/how-to-logout-from-shared-folder) (microsoft.com), which recommends:

1. `net use * /del` (or whatever server).
2. Clear credentials from Credential Manager.
3. Restart the Workstation service.

This procedure worked for me. There was nothing of interest in the Credential Manager, as I did not save credentials, however restarting the Workstation service after clearing the connections with `net` was the key (I did have to close all explorer windows to get the service to restart).

**My question is:** This is not very convenient at all, especially when I have to explain it to less tech-savvy users. While I could certainly create e.g. a batch script to automate the whole thing, is there an actual, proper, consistent way to do this that doesn't involve restarting services (and possibly doesn't involve the command line, although personally I don't mind)?

**Also, a sub-question:** It is weird to me that the vast majority of resources I found on this matter didn't suggest restarting Workstation, and the suggested process of using `net use` alone seemed to work at least for the other people who posted comments on those posts. Is the Workstation restart unique to me and indicative of some other issue on my machine, or was it just left out of all the instructions for some reason? Only the microsoft.com support post had instructions that recommended this step, which is what finally got it working for me.

Logging out of a share seems like it would be a common enough use case to justify some simple way to do it, so I am baffled by how difficult it was for me to figure this out.

---

Other things I've tried with no effect:

- Closing all Explorer windows before and after using `net use` commands (as suggested in [Kody Browns's answer](https://superuser.com/a/883789/245945)), as well as futzing with the "separate process per folder window" settings hoping it was some sort of per-process credential caching (also inspired by that answer).
- Changing homegroup connection management settings (suggested by *holmzi_online*'s answer at the above microsoft.com post).
- Killing all explorer processes (including the main one) and restarting explorer after `net use * /del` (suggested by [Robert Greer here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b611f1e0-2364-455c-b2ae-e6bd0c73bb86/mapped-drive-will-not-disconnect), although that issue was with mapped drives).

Comment: http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles-tutorials/windows-2003/Implementing-Access-Based-Enumeration-Windows-Server-2003.html

Comment: @sttr Thanks, but I'm not sure I see the connection between this and that article. Can you give a hint?

Comment: Hint that mode ABE each user sees only the folders and files which he is entitled. Otherwise, the user must be self-sufficient in order to access the resources and without the need to enter a password. If the "server" is Windows 7, then look http://www.slickit.ca/2009/07/webdav-on-windows-7.html

Comment: @STTR Thanks. How does hiding folders from unauthorized users or setting up a WebDAV server help log out of a SMB share accessed by typing \\address?

Comment: This is an alternative solution for access to shared resources. As far as I understand the question in the number of connections through SMB?

Comment: @STTR The question is, as the title implies, how to log out from a shared folder (SMB, which is what Windows uses for "shared folders") without restarting the Workstation service (see also, *"I logged in as one user, without saving credentials, and now wish to log out"*). I'm not adding WebDAV to my servers, nor can I add WebDAV services to servers I have no control over, nor am I clear on how that solves the problem of logging out conveniently. Do you know how to log out of a shared folder?

Comment: Did you try disconnecting from the IPC$ share on the target computer explicitly? Something like `net use \\server\IPC$ /delete`.

Comment: @DanielB Yes, I did try that, actually. I tried explicitly deleting all connections by name, including *IPC$*, as well as the shotgun approach of just using `*`. Both had the same results. Significant, I think, is that Explorer remains able to access the share even though `net use` displayed no connections remaining at all (not even *IPC$*) after `/del`. And it's not some kind of caching: I could still modify data, see changes other users made, and access folders that I had not previously visited in that session.

Comment: Well, that’s odd. Usually, connecting with Explorer creates a connection to `IPC$` and disconnecting from it leads to Explorer prompting for the password again. When you say you logged in, did you enter your credentials in the dialog? Or are your local login credentials perhaps matching (username/password) the remote credentials?

Comment: @DanielB Entered credentials in the dialog. Username is different than local username. I know it's odd (at least based on my research, where I seem to be in the minority with this issue). In my "sub-question", I wonder if it's indicative of some other issue. But, it's also curious to me that the microsoft.com answer suggested restarting Workstation (which worked); clearly somebody somewhere is aware of something related to this and knew that restarting that service would have an effect. So there must be something to it.

Comment: I'm curious if you ever figured this out? :)

Comment: @Kody Nope, never. I ended up writing a batch script to restart Workstation and stuck a shortcut to it in the quick launch bar, which works for me at least. For users where I was personally setting things up I did the same for them and instructed them when to click it. For everybody else, I just say "reboot the machine". It was a disappointing resolution.

Comment: I went through all the same thinking and trial and error that you did before discovering your post. I'm assuming you've not made any headway since last comment?

Comment: @gwideman Yup, I've got nothing new on this.

Comment: Five years later, Windows 10 Enterprise, same problem. However, your post is the first I've heard of stopping Workstation, so thanks for that. I knew about deleting credentials from the vault and deleting open connections in net use, but like you often found I was still logged into the network drive. For me, when I tried stopping Workstation from a cmd line it informed me I had to stop "Netlogon" and "Computer Browser" services as well. After doing so, and restarting all three, I'm finally disconnected.

Answer (score 5):

Start -> Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> User Accounts -> Manage your credentials.

Expand one of your "Windows Credentials", and then click on "Remove from vault".

[image: Start -> Control Panel]

[image: Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety]

[image: User Accounts and Family Safety -> User Accounts]

[image: User Accounts -> Manage your credentials]

[image: Log out]

[image: Yes]

Comment: Even Faster: [start-menu] - type "cred" and it should find Credentials Manager straight off.   This is what worked for me so thank you.

Comment: For whose like me, who wanted to change the user and, for some reason couldn't find the credentials in the Control Panel, you can overwrite previous user by a new user with : 
`net use [IP] /user:[corporate]\[username] [password]`

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by doing the following:

1. Run `net use * /delete`
2. Clear the credentials (e.g. mine is 172.26.190.129, and the date of create is today, just it)
3. Disable "local connect" (Control Panel\Networking and Internet\Net Connect\Local Connect)
4. Wait a moment (I don't why but I think it may break some links from my Win7 to Ubuntu and may clear some cache)
5. Enable "local connect"
   and it worked..

Comment: What do you mean by "Clear the credentials" and how do you do that?

Comment: "Clear the credentials" is entirely unclear here.

Comment: I think its a reference to the prompt you get after entering the `net use * /delete` command: `Continuing will cancel the connections. Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N)`.

Comment: For step 2 me it worked by clearing them from the Credential Manager (type it in the search box), inside the web credentials section. There I found the credentials for shared drives connections

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but too long for a comment:

This happened to me. For me, the local computer is Windows 10 21H2 and the remote computer is Windows 7.

Special case maybe: remote computer had "advanced sharing settings" - "public folder sharing" - as ON. This means, first time I went to `\\COMPUTERNAME` it logged in as "guest". No username / password prompt.

I know I was guest, because from the local computer on the remote computer I made a file in `c:\users\public\public documents\` (which is accessible as guest) and then checked the owner of that file using properties - security - advanced - owner. (Note, the guest account displays as off in user accounts - manage accounts. I guess it's still active for network login though.)

So if I had first tried to access a protected resource, I might have been forced to provide a username password and then I probably would not have noticed this issue.

Note, I can confirm I also have no cached credentials listed in credential manager. However, other people on the internet do, and removing those fixes it for them (eg: https://serverfault.com/questions/911503/how-to-log-out-from-network-path). I wonder if I don't because I'm logged in as guest. So there's not *really* a credential. But then again there is enough of one I can't use another. But this would be a different situation than OP who logged in explicitly the first time (unless somehow he *still* logged in as guest? In which case the access requirements of the first thing you try to access remotely may play a role here.)

And I tried all these and they didn't work and all said "network connection could not be found":

```
net use \\COMPUTERNAME /delete
net use \\COMPUTERNAME\IPC$ /delete
net use \\COMPUTERNAME\ADMIN$ /delete
net use * /delete
```

One more tidbit: on the local computer I used Process Explorer to search for a string among all processes and I searched for the remote computer name. It yielded an open file handle in the `svchost` for the `Workstation` service. Force-closing that handle via procexp did not help, unfortunately.

But I believe it lends strength to the suspicion that the `Workstation` service is caching these credentials in an inaccessible way.

So for me, restarting the `Workstation` (aka `LanmanWorkstation`) service fixed it. (Note: you can't really do this in powershell, at least v5.1. Because `Workstation` has dependent services. You'd have to extract those, find out which ones are running, stop them, store that list, restart `LanmanWorkstation -force` (which I believe causes dependent services to die ungracefully), then restart the dependent services that were running previously. Oh, and do this recursively for all dependents of dependents and so on. However, `services.msc` does it all for you. For me the only dependent service that `services.msc` restarted was `Computer Browser` aka `browser`)

Comment: Thanks for this btw. It's crazy to me that 3 major versions and 7 years later, this is still a challenge. Good sleuthing with procexp. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1):

2) You are not alone in this issue. Most people probably never experience it because they only have one user and/or multiple users but all with the same password. I seem to experience it all the time. I'm assuming it is because I have the same user name on multiple computers but with different passwords.. (I am not in a domain; laptop is Windows 8.1 with Windows and Linux-based servers..)

(from memory)
If I open the root share of a computer, such as \raspi, before accessing a locked down share such as \raspi\private I will have that issue. It seems that a connection is made using the public/open share first and then it gets stored.

As for 1), I only need to close the Explorer windows and (sometimes command prompts) that have accessed that share. I have never had to restart the workstation service.

But it may work for me because I always tell Windows to "launch folder windows in a separate process"..

Just a thought..

Comment: Thanks!! I was really hoping your suggestion of closing the explorer windows would be the simple fix (I also have separate processes per folder windows), maybe some per-process cached credentials. Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick, nor did disabling separate processes per window. I also didn't see any change in behavior if I tried to access *\\1.2.3.4\Share* first instead of the root (also no difference in accessing by host name rather than IP). I'm also not in a domain, and using Windows and Linux based servers. Something is saving credentials or connections, but I don't know what.

Comment: Another data point: Regardless of the process-per-folder settings, killing all explorer processes (including the main one) and restarting explorer also had no effect, which surprised me.

Comment: I am about to play around with my environment a little bit to test this out more, and had a thought.. your windows (explorer, command prompt, etc.) are all Elevated or all not, right? I've been frustrated many times when I didn't realize or forgot one of my apps was elevated.. It does some weird things to network shares...

Comment: The account I have been using is an administrator and everything is elevated. I created a new non-administrator account and tested from there, the behavior is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions at [Resolving a Windows Error 1219](https://help.altaro.com/hc/en-us/articles/4416905904657-Resolving-a-Windows-Error-1219#:%7E:text=A%20Windows%20Error%201219%20occurs,result%20in%20such%20an%20error.) from Altaro.com worked for me. In particular, downloading [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), choosing `Find/Find Handle or DLL`, and searching for the name of my server revealed that opening a Windows Explorer window with quick links to the server immediately re-established a connection to the server such that `net use \\server` fails with Error 1219. When Process Explorer shows no active handles, `net use \\server` succeeds.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but did you wait long enough after using `net use * /d`?
As far as I know, even after deleting the share, Windows keeps the session open if there are open handles (Explorer window, etc.). And even after closing those handles, there is a time-out period during which it will reconnect the share.
The default seems to be 10-15 minutes. You can shorten this in the registry.

See
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110223-00/?p=11413

However, it seems that "KeepConn" is no longer used in newer versions of Windows. See "Idle Connection Timer" on this page:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2013/03/19/cifs-and-smb-timeouts-in-windows.aspx

Answer (score -1):

```
net use * /del
net stop Workstation /Y
cmdkey /delete:<resourcename>
net start Workstation
net start browser
```

## Way 2: use Multiple NetBIOS names for one computer:

```
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters" /v OptionalNames /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "NetBIOSName01\0 NetBIOSName02\0 NetBIOSName03\0"
```

Then you can connect the resources of different users using different NetBIOS names.

```
net use L: \\NetBIOSName01 /user:<username01> <password01> /P:Yes
net use M: \\NetBIOSName02 /user:<username02> <password02> /P:Yes
net use N: \\NetBIOSName03 /user:<username03> <password03> /P:Yes
```

Edit `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\lmhosts` and add

```
<Server IP>  NetBIOSName01            #PRE
<Server IP>  NetBIOSName02            #PRE
<Server IP>  NetBIOSName03            #PRE
<Server IP>  <OriginalNetBIOSname>            #PRE
```

in all network workstation

All users will connect to its resources.

Comment: As per question title, this doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: Thanks, but this restarts the Workstation service. I mentioned this in the question, but I already know I can automate the restart with a script. Actually, I posted roughly the same command set at http://superuser.com/a/883606/245945. What I'm actually looking for is detailed where I wrote "question" and "sub-question" in bold in my post.

Comment: @JasonC The original cause of all these actions System error 1219?

Comment: @STTR The original cause is a desire to log out without restarting services. The results of my attempts are described in my post.

Comment: @STTR Thanks. The update is interesting and I appreciate your time, but I am unclear about the connection. I'm not trying to map drives or log in with multiple users at the same time. I'm simply trying to log out of a share originally accessed by going directly to \\address. It doesn't necessarily even need to be to switch users. Perhaps I'm just stepping away from the computer and I don't want to leave the share logged in. How will logging in as multiple users over multiple shared drives help to log out of a shared folder without restarting services?

Comment: @JasonC Create multiple users on workstations and add to each share or save the login information for the server resources. Lock your session eg `WindowsKey`+`L`. Now on a workstation can go another user, but it will not get in your session and not see your connected resources.

Comment: @STTR The fact that "how to log out of a shared folder" is ballooning into the creation of multiple workstation accounts, each with credentials saved as different users, is very representative of how circus-like the seemingly simple task of "logging out" is, and is the reason I asked this question. While that is a creative and interesting approach, I do not wish to switch to another local account just to log out of a share (that leads to many other usability problems) and I am not going to instruct users to do that either. *All I want to do is log out of a share.* The opposite of logging in.

Comment: @JasonC O Spherical cow. Then you need a password management system and connect to resources, but the problem is that if you move away and do not remove the details and network connections, the user will have access to the resources of another user. Yes, such a scenario can be realized at powershell for workstations. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Credentials-d44c3cde